# Function to add commas every three digits (thousands separator) is also removing periods from decimals

Tags: jquery

I have a form which is quite large and built using information from a database.

For all fields classed as "numeric", a function is called on key up to automatically add thousand separators. It works well

```
function commas(n){
        n = n.replace(/,/g, '');
        var s=n.split('.')[1];
        (s) ? s='.'+s : s='';
        n=n.split('.')[0]
        while(n.length>3){
            s=','+n.substr(n.length-3,3)+s;
            n=n.substr(0,n.length-3)
        }
        return n+s
    }
```

I have noticed now however that if I want to put a small decimal value into a field which calls this on key up, it removes the period

2.3 => 23

I can't see how this is happening: I wrote this commas function with the help of someone on Stack.

Can anyone advise? Thanks

**Edit:**

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QJU59/) of the phenomenon to proove I'm not making it up ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, but as far as I see, this code should do what you want and I can't manage to reproduce the bug. http://jsfiddle.net/bX92V/ Perhaps there is something else that is the cause of your problem?

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle where this problem occurs. I can't reproduce it either.

Comment: Same here. jsFiddle or doesn't exist.

Comment: Quite right you are - so strange. I don't have any other functions being called on that element, that's very odd. I'll have to have a think about how to debug that

Comment: Did it! Must be to do with me the way I'm calling it? - here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QJU59/

Comment: Ah, I think we are looking at two different problems. There's nothing wrong with your function, but you are however applying it incorrectly. How you have written your code, it will strip away superfluous decimal points without following decimals (e.g '2.'=>2). However, since you are actually changing the form itself it will be impossible to write any decimal values since the dot will be removed before you get a chance to write any decimal numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that as soon as you enter '.', the code sees that there is nothing after it and set s = ''. The effect is that every time your enter '.', it's removed again.

Try something like this:

```
function commas(n) {
    n = n.replace(/,/g, '');
    var s = n.split('.')[1];
    (s)
        ? s = '.' + s
        : n.indexOf('.') >= 0
            ? s = '.'
            : s = '';
    n = n.split('.')[0];
    while (n.length > 3) {
        s = ',' + n.substr(n.length - 3, 3) + s;
        n = n.substr(0, n.length - 3);
    }
    return n + s;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted? The problem was reproduced (http://jsfiddle.net/HkcPw/) and the above fixes it.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort! I didn't down vote you, indeed, perhaps someone just didn't believe you'd reproduced it. Seems very strange that the way the commenter above called the function does not produce the issue however? I'll cast you an upvote to undo the down

Comment: While I didn't down vote, initially this seems to fix a different problem than what was stated in the question (2.3=>23), but now it seems like this is in fact the problem he was trying to explain.

Comment: I've removed my downvote. As Daniel said: I thought that that's not the problem. OP's question was not clear enough.

Comment: Thanks Gideon. The reason Daniel's example works is that it's outputting the modified value somewhere else, where as in our examples the value of the text box is being overridden.